# How to add angular2-logger to my Angular4 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, logging

I am trying to add **angular2-logger** to my Angular.
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-logger
told me how to config.It said:Add the angular2-logger library to your app. If you are following the Angular 2's Quickstart Guide it should be something like this:
In **systemjs.config.js**:

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
  'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
  '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
  'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
  'angular2-logger':            'node_modules/angular2-logger' // ADD THIS
};

//packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
  'app':                        { main: 'main.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
  'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'angular2-logger':            { defaultExtension: 'js' }, // AND THIS
};
```

However,When I create **QuickStart** from official web https://angular.io/generated/zips/cli-quickstart/cli-quickstart.zip ,I can't see the file:**systemjs.config**

Who can tell me what should I do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the Angular CLI, you should not need a systemjs.config.js. CLI handles everything. You really shouldn't even need to configure,so just try `npm install --save angular2-logger` then Setup the Provider and Inject the logger into your objects and use it.

Configure the logger:

For dev in `environment.ts`

```
import { Level } from 'angular2-logger/core';
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  logger: {
    level: Level.INFO
  }
};
```

For prod in `environment.prod.ts`

```
import { Level } from 'angular2-logger/core';
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  logger: {
    level: Level.WARN
  }
};
```

Load configuration in `app.module.ts`

```
import { Logger } from 'angular2-logger/core';
import { NgModule, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment }    from '../environments/environment';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ...  ],
  providers: [ Logger ],
  bootstrap: [ ... ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private logger: Logger) {
    if (isDevMode()) {
      console.info('To see debug logs enter: \'logger.level = logger.Level.DEBUG;\' in your browser console');
    }
    this.logger.level = environment.logger.level;
  }
}
```

Usage:

For example in `app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private logger: Logger) {
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.logger.debug('ngOnInit');
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried.But faild.something wrong in my cmd.like this

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-logger/app/core/level.ts
Module build failed: Error: F:\evaluation-system-latest\node_modules\angular2-logger\app\core\level.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Comment: i updated the answer based on an [issue](https://github.com/code-chunks/angular2-logger/issues/79) for using module with CLI,

Comment: it doesnt work for me.But I found [issue](https://github.com/code-chunks/angular2-logger/issues/175) from Aitchy13.I combind you two's solutions.it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the file as "https://angular.io/generated/zips/cli-quickstart/cli-quickstart.zip" is angular version 5.

In the documentation, it is clearly mentioned that if you are using angular2 then you need to configure system.config.js  else you may directly add provider and add it in constructor function and start logging using this module